# Mass Action in Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, order-grid, router, massaction

I want to create new mass action inside Order grid which will create new Shipment but I have problem with my action. When I click submit button my action don't work but only redirect me on homepage.

My `app/code/local/CFO/ShipAction/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <CFO_ShipAction>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </CFO_ShipAction>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <cfoshipaction>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>CFO_ShipAction_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>cfoshipaction</frontName>
            </args>
        </cfoshipaction>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <CFO_ShipAction_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>CFO_ShipAction_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addShipAction</method>
                </CFO_ShipAction_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

My  `app/code/local/CFO/ShipAction/Model/Observer.php`

```
class CFO_ShipAction_Model_Observer
{
    public function addShipAction($observer){
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addItem('cfoshipaction', array(
                'label' => 'Create shipment',
                'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('cfoshipaction/adminhtml_massactions/createShipment')
            ));
        }               
    }
}
```

And `app/code/local/CFO/ShipAction/controllers/Adminhtml/MassActionsController.php`

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Action.php';

class CFO_ShipAction_Adminhtml_MassActionsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {        
    public function createShipmentAction() {
        $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());     
            foreach ($orderIds as $orderId){
                try {
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                    if($order->canShip()) {
                        //Create shipment
                        $shipmentid = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')
                                        ->create($order->getIncrementId(), array());
                        //Add tracking information
                        $ship = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')
                                        ->addTrack($order->getIncrementId(), array());       
                    }
                }catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    print_r($e);
                }
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/');
    }
}
```

I'm know that problem is with my router, but I don't know where. I tried 2 options for initializing my router but both not help. Can anybody see what's missing? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

There is my other `config.xml` with other router which I've tried to use but sill noting:

```
<config>
...
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <CFO_ShipAction before="Mage_Adminhtml">CFO_ShipAction_Adminhtml</CFO_ShipAction>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
</config>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: So, are you saying your observer works, but something doesn't work in the controller action?

Comment: Yes, I have redirected to homepage when I try launch `mywebsite.com/index.php/cfoshipaction/adminhtml_massactions/createShipment/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Problem resolved !**

There was a mistake in my controller. I've chosen other type of router initialize (like my edits) but I forgot about **modules container**, so now my `config.xml` look like:

```
...
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <shipactions after="Mage_Adminhtml">CFO_ShipAction_Adminhtml</shipactions>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
```

Moreover there was a problem with name of Controller. When my name of file is `MassActionsController` with `createShipment Action` then my url is `adminhtml/massActions/createShipment`.

Last thing is disable the Secret Key in URLs. You can find it in `System>Configuration>Security>Add Secret Key to URLs`.